# PHP-Mailform not working on Godaddy, updating settings according to Godady's specs doesn't work

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Edit: The code provider tested the code on their end and it went through successfully, so it's a problem with the way godaddy is handling it.  I replaced all the code with the stock code and started over from scratch.  Godaddy changed the mail routing to their local mail exchanger last night, but still no luck.  After changing the following variables, I am now getting a response from the server when using the form, and it appears to be connecting now, but the entire email message gets dumped in the error log.  I will post it below.
In rd-mailform.php, changed line 107, use TLS, to True, Smtpauth to false, Smtpsecure to none.

In Rd-mailform.config.json, usesmtp to true, localhost, port 25, username and password blank, and specified the recipient email.

error log entry:

```
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] PHP Deprecated:  __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home/fhry8dej5umy/public_html/bat/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 45
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] Connection: opening to localhost:25, t=300, opt=array (
)
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] Connection: opened
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-p3plzcpnl450427.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Fri, 09 Apr 2021 05:58:58 -0700 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO dukecitysecurity.com
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-p3plzcpnl450427.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello dukecitysecurity.com [::1]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<tripind@hotmail.com>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<michael@dukecitysecurity.com>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 9 Apr 2021 12:58:58 +0000
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: To: michael@dukecitysecurity.com
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Michael Kountz <tripind@hotmail.com>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: A message from your site visitor
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <e45062494bee28e71d85f6b8095220a2@dukecitysecurity.com>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:    boundary="b1_e45062494bee28e71d85f6b8095220a2"
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e45062494bee28e71d85f6b8095220a2
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Notification
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Hi, someone left a message for you at dukecitysecurity.com 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: A message from your site visitor
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Email:
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       ****@hotmail.com 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Name:
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Michael K*********
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Phone:
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       **********
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Privacy-Policy-Agreement:
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       Got acknowledged and Agreed
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                 Message:
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply.
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e45062494bee28e71d85f6b8095220a2
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:   <head> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     <title>A message from your site visitor</title>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     <style type="text/css">  
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     #outlook a {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       padding: 0;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     body {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       width: 100% !important;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       margin: 0;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       padding: 0;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       width: 100%;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass,
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass span,
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass font,
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass td,
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass div {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       line-height: 100%;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     .ExternalClass p {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       line-height: inherit;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     #body-layout {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       margin: 0;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       padding: 0;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       width: 100% !important;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       line-height: 100% !important;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     img {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       display: block;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       outline: none;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       text-decoration: none;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     a img {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       border: none;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     table td {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       border-collapse: collapse;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     table {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       border-collapse: collapse;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     a {
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       color: orange;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:       outline: none;
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     }
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:     </style>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:   </head>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:   <body id="body-layout">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>Notification</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>Hi, someone left a message for you at dukecitysecurity.com</td> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: A message from your site visitor
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="center" valign="top">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="center" valign="top">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;">Email:</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">tripind@hotmail.com</td> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <!-- #{BeginInfo} -->
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;"><!-- #{InfoState} --></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;"><!-- #{InfoDescription} --></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:                                       <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;">Name:</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">Michael Kountz</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  <tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER:  <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;">Phone:</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">5053041871</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr> 
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;">Privacy-Policy-Agreement:</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">Got acknowledged and Agreed</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <!-- #{EndInfo} -->                                    
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td height="12" style="height: 12px; line-height:12px;"></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;">Message:</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td height="40" style="height: 40px; line-height:40px;"></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="600" align="center" valign="top">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 400;color: #a1b4c4;">This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply.</td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </td>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </body>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: </html>
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e45062494bee28e71d85f6b8095220a2--
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1lUqiw-00EW1t-Dv
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 p3plzcpnl450427.prod.phx3.secureserver.net closing connection
[09-Apr-2021 12:58:58 Etc/UTC] Connection: closed
```

Comment: This is the same as your other question. I can see you’re using a very old version of PHPMailer, which won’t help. When you inspect your XHRs, look at the actual content of the responses, not just the stats on them.

Comment: The only thing listed under response is "MF000."  Does that mean anything useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an email account hosted by godaddy and specified that account as the sender in rd-mailform.php using the code provided by Synchro.  After that, the form would still send ok, but not get received.  The recipient email was hosted by gmail.  I changed the recipient email to one hosted by hotmail, and the form submissions emailed successfully.  In this case, it looks like the problem was with gmail turning away the email at the door.  The link provided by synchro, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters, would likely help with that, but I don't know how to implement the steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of problems with this script.

First of all you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, which won't help but is probably not the problem here.

The lack of SMTPDebug output is suspicious, but then there is this:

```php
     //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
     $mail->isMail();
```

Unfortunately that does the opposite of what it says. To make it use SMTP it must be `$mail->isSMTP();`. Changing that will likely make a big difference to what you see in your XHR responses.

You have some exception handlers (MF 254 and 255), but they will never trigger because you don't have exceptions enabled. Change `new PHPMailer()` to `new PHPMailer(true)` and see what happens.

The config file includes this:

```
"port": 25,`enter code here`
```

That makes no sense. It should be just `"port": 25,`.

The script does this:

```
$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
```

That's forgery (pretending to send s the person who submitted the form), and will likely result in your messages being bounced or spam-filtered. Do this instead:

```
$mail->From = $addresses[0][0];
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
```

The attachment handling code is unsafe; it trusts what is in the $_FILES array and uses it without checking. That's too complex to fix here.

If this script is something you paid for, I recommend asking them for support. It's really not very good, and you shouldn't be having to deal with this kind of problem as a user.

Comment: Thank you, Synchro.  I made the changes, but no improvement.  I spent all day yesterday in chat with the hosting provider trying to figure it out, they said it's a problem with the code.  I've been emailing customer support at the site the code came from, and they can't figure out why it's not working, either, and trying to say that it's a problem with the host.  The host sent me here, which didn't help:  https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953

Comment: So are you still seeing nothing in your XHR responses? You might be better off scrapping the whole thing and starting again with a better known-good script, like the examples provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: xhr says the same thing as before; MF000, which I found in the code as meaning that the email was sent successfully.  I don't have the ability to scrap it for something else, unfortunately.  I'm stuck trying to make this one work.  I do appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: Make sure you’re actually running the right script. If the output doesn’t change when it should, suspect everything. Change that mf000 line to something like `var_dump($mail)` and it should be much noisier.

Comment: I'm trying to add the code from that mf000 section to ask how to change it, but I am having formatting problems:                                                          // RD Mailform
  if (plugins.rdMailForm.length) {
   var i, j, k,
    msg = {
     'MF000': 'Successfully sent!',
     'MF001': 'Recipients are not set!',
     'MF002': 'Form will not work locally!',
     'MF003': 'Please, define email field in your form!',
     'MF004': 'Please, define type of your form!',
     'MF254': 'Something went wrong with PHPMailer!',
     'MF255': 'Aw, snap! Something went wrong.'
    }; `

Comment: It's from the script.js file, in another folder

Comment: I changed smtp to "true" in the rd-mailform.config.json file and got a noisy xhr response.  There's more, but this was the first and most important looking line:  SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-p3plzcpnl450427.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Sun, 04 Apr 2021 15:05:07 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Comment: I didn’t mention it before because you already had that set in the code you posted. That response is not an error, just a “welcome” banner. The real issue will be later. Post it in your question, not comments.

Comment: I made some progress with both the code provider and the hosting service.  I edited the post to reflect that.  Still not getting where I need to be, but I am at least connecting to the server now.  I had to delete the original post to make room to post the error log info.

Comment: Where it says `SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK` – that means that your message *send* was successful. Whether you *receive* it is a separate matter, but your sending is working, though several of the points I raised remain. Check your spam folder.

Comment: Still not receiving, even in he spam folder.  Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Given that you're using GoDaddy and forging your from address, I expect your messages are being bounced or spam filtered somewhere along the line, so [read the docs on that](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters). I'm surprised that GoDaddy even lets you send like that. You're using not just an *outdated* version of PHPMailer, but an *ancient* one from 2014 that is known to have major security vulnerabilities that could be used to compromise your whole server. You really need to update.

Comment: It should not be forging anything.  I updated that part of the code again, just now ($mail->From = $_POST['email'];) like you suggested, but the result is the same.   Upgrading the code to a new version is not something I'm capable of doing, unfortunately.  So I'm stuck trying to make this work.

Comment: You are forging because the address you're sending from is a hotmail address, and you can only send from hotmail addresses by sending through hotmail servers, but you're sending through GoDaddy. That will cause an SPF failure because it's effectively forgery. Your original code would *guarantee* it was always forgery; my suggestion avoids that, but also requires that the address you set as your from address is one you're actually allowed to send from through that server. If you're going send through GoDaddy, you need to use a GoDaddy address, or have them handle your domain's mail.

Comment: OK, thank you.  There is a default email account hosted by godaddy that is not managed by google, which manages all the other emails @dukecitysecurity.com.  I changed the from email to that in the code.  I am still getting everything sent ok, but nothing is getting received.